# Table to DIV and CSS

Tags: css, html

**Question:** *Can this be done using DIVs and CSS? (instead of a html table)*

---

A table with 3 columns and 3 rows, horizontally aligned to center and vertically aligned to top.
When the content in the middle cell is bigger, then entire table is expanded to left, right and bottom.

*`Left`* and *`right`* columns width, *`top`* and *`bottom`* rows height shall not change.

[image]

*The gray borders which can be seen in this picture are not important, they are invisible actually.*

Comment: `div { display:table/table-row/table-cell }` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the values `inline-table`, `table`, `table-caption`, `table-cell`, `table-column`, `table-column-group`, `table-row`, `table-row-group`, and `inherit` are not supported in IE7 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

CSS display Property values, use these

> ```
> table Let the element behave like a <table> element   
> table-caption Let the element behave like a <caption> element 
> table-column-group    Let the element behave like a <colgroup> element    
> table-header-group    Let the element behave like a <thead> element   
> table-footer-group    Let the element behave like a <tfoot> element   
> table-row-group   Let the element behave like a <tbody> element   
> table-cell    Let the element behave like a <td> element  
> table-column  Let the element behave like a <col> element 
> table-row Let the element behave like a <tr> element
> ```

more reference: [CSS display Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

So, documentation says, these values have only support with IE8 onwards, so you have to use the `<table>` element in IE7.